# What are the effects of padding a tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensor

I'm working on a problem using Keras that has been presenting me with issues:

My X data is all of shape (`num_samples`, 8192, 8), but my Y data is of shape (`num_samples`, 4), where `4` is a one-hot encoded vector.

Both X and Y data will be run through LSTM layers, but the layers are rejecting the Y data because it doesn't match the shape of the X data.

Is padding the Y data with 0s so that it matches the dimensions of the X data unreasonable? What kind of effects would that have? Is there a better solution?

**Edited for clarification:**
As requested, here is more information:

My Y data represents the expected output of passing the X data through my model. This is my first time working with LSTMs, so I don't have an architecture in mind, but I'd like to use an architecture that works well with classifying long (8192-length) sequences of words into one of several categories. Additionally, the dataset that I have is of an immense size when fed through an LSTM, so I'm currently using batch-training.

Technologies being used:

- Keras (Tensorflow Backend)

TL;DR **Is padding one tensor with zeroes in all dimensions to match another tensor's shape a bad idea? What could be a better approach?**

Comment: "will be run through LSTM layers"
Are those the same LSTM layers, or is Y your expected output after passing X through your LSTM layers? Try to give some more information on what exactly your network architecture is and/or what your training goals are.

Comment: Updated @KonstantinosKokos!

Comment: Hey, [very similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303489/best-way-to-mini-batch-similar-lengths-sequences-in-a-corpus-for-rnn-training/303501#303501) was asked on cross-validated

Comment: I think the two questions are unrelated.

Comment: @JakubBartczuk thank you for the link! I didn't know training on a standardized certain length of would intoduce bias. Is that in regards to length of each sample, or the number of samples?

Additionally, all of my X-data samples are the same in terms of shape, it's the Y-data (which should be the output of the model after X-data is passed through it) that is of a different shape than the X-data.

Comment: Length of the sequences, of course. I haven't actually seen anything that changes batch size dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's make sure your representation is actually what you think it is; the input to an LSTM (or any recurrent layer, for that matter) must be of dimensionality: (timesteps, shape), i.e. if you have 1000 training samples, each consisting of 100 timesteps, with each timestep having 10 values, your input shape will be (100,10,). Therefore I assume from your question that each input sample in your X set has 8192 steps and 8 values per step. Great; a single LSTM layer can iterate over these and produce 4-dimensional representations with absolutely no problem, just like so:

```python
myLongInput = Input(shape=(8192,8,))
myRecurrentFunction = LSTM(4)
myShortOutput = myRecurrentFunction(myLongInput)
myShortOutput.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(4)])
```

I assume your problem stems from trying to apply yet another LSTM on top of the first one; the next LSTM expects a tensor that has a time dimension, but your output has none. If that is the case, you'll need to let your first LSTM also output the intermediate representations at each time step, like so:

```python
myNewRecurrentFunction=LSTM(4, return_sequences=True)
myLongOutput = myNewRecurrentFunction(myLongInput)
myLongOutput.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(4)])
```

As you can see the new output is now a 3rd order tensor, with the second dimension now being the (yet unassigned) timesteps. You can repeat this process until your final output, where you usually don't need the intermediate representations but rather only the last one. (Sidenote: make sure to set the activation of your last layer to a softmax if your output is in one-hot format)

On to your original question, zero-padding has very little negative impact on your network. The network will strain itself a bit in the beginning trying to figure out the concept of the additional values you have just thrown at it, but will very soon be able to learn they're meaningless. This comes at a cost of a larger parameter space (therefore more time and memory complexity), but doesn't really affect predictive power most of the time.

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful!

However, this seems to address only the provided X-data shape, which is where I am currently stuck. How would I address the fact that my Y-data shape doesn't match the X-data shape, as the X-data is of shape (`num_samples`, 8192, 8) and my Y-data is of shape (`num_samples`, 4)?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite clear on what the problem is; the toy network above is now outputing (None, 4) dimensional tensors, which is your Y format. Are you getting some error message or is your intuition not satisfied? :)

Comment: I'm getting an error message. I think you explained what was occurring in the model excellently, and it makes perfect sense. I'll test what you've said above, and report back! Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure! If you encounter any problems feel free to ask

Comment: Your answer works!

While my model performs poorly, it is training correctly! Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: You have an extreme amount of data and even LSTMs aren't capable of retaining memory over these many timesteps, so careful fine-tuning and patience will probably be required to increase performance. I am glad that at least you got it to work though! Best of luck with your project